# Is there ornamental addon?

Tags: add-on

[image: I want to create the ornamental shape. Is there any addon available that can make as the image shown below.] I want to create the ornamental shape. Is there any addon available that can make as the image shown below. i want to make that shape and twist around the chair

[image]

Comment: I don't think so, but you could set that as a background, model out the shape, then add some depth?

Comment: No addon that I know of. Best I can think of is the [Ornaments Collection](https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/pearlworks-60-items-collection/) over at the Blender Market (commercial payed model pack)

Comment: If you really want those details as geometry you'll need to model them, and that's quite complex, see https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?277242-Blender-Baroque-%28organic-modeling-and-retopology%29 for details. In general that's usage of F2 addon. You could fake that geometry if it's far from camera to make it easier.

Comment: If you don't need lot of realism, also a (specially crafted) texture displacement could give some basic results, maybe ot refine later (eg: with sculpting)

Comment: I recently saw [a great video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=DUibqoat_gE) demonstrating how this can be done. It's a modeling time-lapse, not a tutorial, but I think it will show you most of what you need to know.